# How to instruct PowerShell to export a function name as a cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

This is a follow-up to

[Writing a cmdlet in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69372648/writing-a-cmdlet-in-powershell)

There I got this link about how to declare a function as a cmdlet:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/09-functions?view=powershell-7.1#advanced-functions

Using yet another page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.1

I tried

```
function Send-Greeting
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Name
    )

    Process
    {
        Write-Host ("Hello " + $Name + "!")
    }
}
```

I ran this script but it did not work as expected:

```
PS > .\Send-Greeting.ps1
PS > Send-Greeting Joe                                                                                                   Send-Greeting : The term 'Send-Greeting' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Send-Greeting Joe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Send-Greeting:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How can I export my new cmdlet into the PowerShell environment so that I could use it as a builtin cmdlet?

Comment: Change `.\Send-Greeting.ps1` to `. .\Send-Greeting.ps1` - dot-sourcing it will ensure the function definition persists in the callers scope

Answer (score 2):

Three things:

- put this code into a module, that is, a .psm1 file
- export the function with the Export-ModuleMember cmdlet
- import this module into the PowerShell environment with the Import-Module cmdlet

So save this to Send-Greeting.psm1:

```
function Send-Greeting
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Name
    )

    Process
    {
        Write-Host ("Hello " + $Name + "!")
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Send-Greeting
```

and invoke

```
PS > Import-Module .\Send-Greeting.psm1
```

After that, the whole thing works:

```
PS > Send-Greeting -Name Joe 
Hello Joe!
```

Literature:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember?view=powershell-7.1

https://superuser.com/a/1583330/216969